# Image is visible but text is not visible in ListView

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am trying to create a custom layout for list view in android studio. I was able to successfully get image in the in ListView on runtime but wasn't able to print text in the list view . When i run my program in emulator it runs without any error but it doesn't show any text it only shows image from drawables.

[image]

> MainActivity.java

```
    import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private final  static String[] names={"A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A",
            "A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A",};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ListView ls = findViewById((R.id.customlistview));
        ls.setAdapter(new CustomListAdapter(getApplicationContext(),names,R.drawable.za));
    }
}
```

> activity_main.xml

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/customlistview"
        android:layout_width="409dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

> CustomListAdapter.java

```
    import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class CustomListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private final Context context;
    private final String[] names;
    private final int image;
    private final LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

    public  CustomListAdapter(Context context,String[] names,int image) {

        this.context=context;
        this.image=image;
        this.names=names;
        layoutInflater= (LayoutInflater) this.context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return names.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View rootview;
        rootview = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_layout, null);
        TextView tv= rootview.findViewById(R.id.textView);
        ImageView iv=rootview.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        tv.setText(names[position]);
        iv.setImageResource(image);
        return rootview;

    }
}
```

> list_item_layout.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:height="70dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I used exactly your code to reproduce. I got the text displayed. What I changed is  ```ls.setAdapter(new CustomListAdapter(getApplicationContext(), names, R.drawable.common_signin_btn_icon_dark));``` since I dont have your drawable.

Comment: I tried it with a different drawable but outcome is still the same not text visible

Comment: @HarryQ when i used android.R.layout it showed texts

Comment: have you tried ```Tools->Layout Inspector``` to see if your text view is layout correctly?

Comment: I am using ```compileSdkVersion 28```, ```implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'```, ```implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'``` in my gradle. Also running on a emulator of ```pixel 2 API 28```. Not sure why it is shown on my end, but not yours. Or can you share your project folder somewhere I can download and start from there?

Comment: Why are you using ListView, you should use RecyclerView

Comment: @FacuArg i am currently learning so i thought of starting from ListView and then move to RecyclerView

Comment: @HarryQ  It was happening because of the text color , noticed it after using layout inspector.

Comment: If the answer below does not solve your issue, don't tick it as accepted answer.  Other people could be misled by it. Instead, you should post your solution as answer.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is in your list_item_layout file. There is an issue with match_parent in your layout try using below code

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:weightSum="3"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:height="70dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="TextView"
    android:textSize="18sp" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem was caused by the text colour , changing the colour of textview text in list_item_layout resolved the issue.